# Accessing Google Maps from EPUB

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, epub

Attempting to access Google Maps from EPUB document. Have XHTML compliant file, based on Google Maps sample code, that has no problem accessing Google Maps when invoked from IE 9.0 or Safari 5.1.2 but goes dead when invoked from Apple iBook EPUB. Search of Google Code for "EPUB" gives zero matches. Have seen examples of EPUBs that access Google Maps, but those examples use subterfuge of first shelling out to Safari, then connecting to a tinyurl.com page, then connecting to Google Maps. Want to access Google Maps directly from EPUB without shelling out to Safari and without using tinyurl.com or any other web page or resource. Apple iBook appears to intercept and block any HTTP URL that contains a question mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SVG

[Illustrated ebooks with epub: using the svg image element](http://denis.papathanasiou.org/?p=592)

Comment: Sorry, it is not a simple static JPEG that I am attempting to display; my iBook product has hundreds of JPEGs, some of which I display in "then" and "now" pairs on a single page, without problem. It is accessing Google Maps interactively, which must be painted with data downloaded dynamically from the Google Maps server, that iBooks appear to block.

Comment: My demo has a dynamic google map using SVG    [map](http://daviestrachan.zxq.net/maps/svgmap.xml)

Comment: many thanks for your help. If I click on the link you provide from Safari on my MacBook or iPad, your basic map pops up just fine. But the behavior within my iBook is not quite right. I downloaded the source to svgmap.xml and basicmap.html. I placed both files in my EPUB document structure. In the OPF document, manifest section, I placed the following:

Comment: Safari on iPad map is OK. But iBook is NG. Downloaded svgmap.xml and basicmap.html. Placed both files in EPUB. OPF manifest has:

    <item id="svgmap" href="svgmap.xml" media-type="image/svg+xml" />
    <item id="basicmap" href="basicmap.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />

Spine section has:

    <itemref idref="svgmap" />
    <itemref idref="basicmap" />

Navigation document has:

        <li><a href="svgmap.xml">Basic Map</a></li>

Touch Basic Map in TOC, get one page of the SVG box, canted 20 degrees, and within the box, text of basicmap.html starting at the #map text line.

Comment: EPUB on iPad shows no map, no access to Google Maps, only source text of basicmap.html. Was your demo intended for EPUB / iBook?